# Unable to run pm2 with npx babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, pm2

I have a Node.js app that perfectly works with the following command:

```
npx babel-node dist/index.js
```

However, I'm not able to run this with pm2. When I do the following:

```
pm2 start --interpreter npx babel-node dist/index.js
```

Obviously, this does not work. And when I try:

```
pm2 start --interpreter babel-node dist/index.js
```

This does not work either, as my global babel is version `6.26.3` and my project babel is `7.0.0-0`.

Is there a way to make pm2 to play nice with npx or maybe there is a way to upgrade the system wide babel to `7.0`?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to create a `build` and a `start` script in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npx babel src -d dist",
  "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js"
},
```

And then run the pm2 using the start option:

```
pm2 start npm --name "app name" -- start
```

Comment: When I start in that way, I'm still getting an error. `/myapp/dist/index.js:15  import mongoose from 'mongoose';` the error is not there when I just run it normally.

Comment: Later things are running fine, but this initial error is strange. I don't get that error if I just run straight from the terminal. In fact, I have created a `run.sh` bash script that has `npx babel-node dist/index.js` in there and when I do `pm2 start run.sh` it all works. But the fact that the generic approach is not working is really strange.

Comment: Odd, maybe we need to build before, I updated my answer to add the build before, try to run again

Comment: I have modules in there as well, what would be the proper command to compile the whole ./dist hierarchy? `I'm getting an error now: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /myapp/dist/modules/config.mjs`

Comment: don't you have a source directory? I don't know why want to compile the dust directory, normally we need to compile the src directory and use the dist directory to serve, put everything inside your source module and leave the dist empty before the build.

Comment: When I compile, it converts all my *.mjs files in the ./src/modules/ to *.js files. Then when I run `node index.js` from with in ./dist it complains about not being able to import the modules. Anyway, I'm giving up. It is too late, this is completely broken.

Comment: I can try to help you if you want, but I need to understand your structure, can you share the github source?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I was running out of time and the bash-script seems to be working for now. I eventually will come back and try to solve this. Thanks for the support.